# C++ priority_queue doesn't have push?

Tags: c++, xcode, stl, priority-queue

I have these at the top of my file:

```
#include <queue>

typedef struct cell_s {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;
    unsigned int ambiguity = 9;
} cell_t;

// so the priority_queue can sort the structs:
bool operator<(const cell_t &a, const cell_t &b) {
    return a.ambiguity < b.ambiguity;
}
```

In the same file I have declared a priority_queue as a private member of a class, like this:

```
priority_queue<cell_t> blankCellQueue;
```

Then I have a member function of the same class that contains these lines:

```
cell_t cell;
cell.x = x;
cell.y = y;
blankCellQueue.push(cell);
```

But Xcode is presenting this warning on the last line I shared:

"No matching member function for call to 'push'".

Comment: Why do you declare your struct C like when your using C++?

Comment: Complete example please.

Comment: Are there any other errors generated by the compiler?

Comment: Check that you do not have some other header file included that defines a different version of `priority_queue`.

Comment: @Caesar - I only needed to store data. Unless I'm mistaken, there's some overhead with using a class instead of a struct, is there not? It's just as easy to type `struct` as it is to type `class`, so why not?

No other errors are being generated.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare In C++ the only difference between `struct` and `class` is that by default `struct` members are public where as `class` has it is member as `private` by default

Comment: @Caesar - Sounds like in this case, using a `struct` is right then, no, since I wanted all of the members to be `public` - it wouldn't have made sense to make them `private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to have wasted all of your time. I found the issue. The priority_queue is a member of my class. The function I was attempting to edit the priority_queue from was a member function that I had marked as const, because I hadn't anticipated a need to modify any class variables when I originally wrote it without any queue. Invoking push on a member object from a const member function is an obvious no-no. I just wish Xcode had given a slightly useful error messages... something along the lines of "non const function invoked from const function" would be a very helpful message.

Since I hadn't provided the member function declaration, it would have been very difficult for anyone to have pointed that out to me here.

Thanks for the offers of help!

Answer (score 2):

`priority_queue` is part of the namespace, `std`. You need to use `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: If that was the case shouldn't the error be on the declaration and not the push. But than again he might not have his errors in the right order.

Comment: Both would be errors, you're right. And, yeah, the code he's presented is incomplete, so I'm assuming the errors may incomplete as well.

Comment: Is it defined where a compiler will flag the error? If it's an error at declaration _and_ use, does the compiler have to point out the error at declaration? I don't know how that works.

Comment: I've seen compilers give an error at declaration, but proceed assuming the declared variable is an `int`, later giving additional errors because the `int` doesn't have member functions.

Answer (score 1):

C++11's [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) is a standard container adapter and it *does* have member function `push()` - see the linked reference.

It is possible, though, that your implementation of the C++ Standard Library is not compliant. You should upgrade to the latest version.

You can see your code compiling [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3SpAkW%2437). It required adding the `std::` namespace qualifier before `priority_queue`, but I do not believe that to be the root cause of the issue here. If it were, your compiler error should be different (or you should receive other errors before).

Comment: Push has been there before C++11

Comment: You *did* add `std::` to `priority_queue` :)

Comment: @Sancho: Right, I had to, but I am assuming the OP has a `using namespace std` or a `using` declaration in his header, otherwise the compiler would emit an error way before getting to the call to `push()`.

Comment: Yeah, the asker needs to clarify if the compiler gave other errors before the one they listed... it's not a very complete question. As it stands, you and I are both just guessing.

Comment: @Sancho - I do have `using namespace std` in my code. I am not receiving any errors besides this one.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: What is your compiler?

Comment: @AndyProwl: Clang, I think. I'm using whatever comes with Xcode 4.6.